# How can I use the result of a multi-value returning function as the argument of another function in Golang if I don't need error handling?

Tags: go

The following is what I want to achieve

```
fmt.Println(string(ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)))
```

But this throws the following error.

```
multiple-value ioutil.ReadAll() in single-value context
```

I know that ioutil.ReadAll() returns the bytes and the error. But I don't want to write an extra line as follows

```
bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Is it possible to just pass the result of ioutil.ReadAll() to fmt.Println() if don't care abut error handling in Go?

Comment: You cannot. Sorry. No need to try, its undoable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it only once, it makes little sense in my opinion. However if this is a common situation and you feel that it improves code readability a lot, try something like:

```
// perhaps, there's a better name for this
func resultToString(b []byte, _ error) string { 
    return string(b)
}

// and later:
fmt.Println(resultToString(ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)))
```

Unfortunately, that's a string-specific function, so for any other type you'll need to duplicate it.

Comment: ioutil.ReadAll actually return bytes, right? So this means that I will have to write similar functions for all types in go.

Comment: @aswinmprabhu `[]byte` indeed, updated the answer. Yes, until Go gets some generic types, you will have to duplicate it for every type you need.

Comment: Just as a statement of intent, I'd also change the arguments to `(b []byte, _ error)`. The underscore makes it obvious that the error is going to be ignored

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem good point, will update.

Comment: I'd be very, very wary of any program that suppresses so many errors that it needs a helper (or multiple helpers) to do it. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Adrian valid point, though in testing code redundancy is often pain, also some functions like `json.Marshal` are not likely to return error, even though it's in the signature.